# PHP How do I make a new file for every time user clicks button

Tags: php, file

So basically what I want is a program where the user inputs something in a textarea, the php then stores the input in a new file every time this is done. Here is what I've got so far:

This gets the input from the user.

```
<?php
$usrUp = $_POST['input'];
$fOp = fopen("updates.txt","c+");
fwrite($fOp, $usrUp);
fclose ( $fOp );
?>
```

And this is supposed to create a new file with the new information.

```
<?php
if (file_exists ("updates.txt") && filesize ("updates.txt") > 0) 
{
$open = fopen("updates.txt","r");
$contentU = fread($open, filesize("updates.txt"));
fclose ($open);
echo $contentU;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you need, each time user makes an input to store in a new file (and leaves old). Or each time each user makes input it will overwrite an "updates.txt" (1 file for all).

Comment: First off: Consider using a database for this kind of stuff. It's easy to set up, xampp even comes with mysql. To answer your question: Is it supposed to make a new file every time you run this? Eg resulting in inp1.txt, inp2.txt, inp3.txt and so on. Why not just do a while(true) loop that counts up the file names until file_exists returns false, in which case you create the file and break out of the loop?

Comment: Answer to Ultrazz: In the example above it inputs and overwrites what is already in "updates.txt." This was just a temporary solution for me, but I do want it to make a new file and leave the old one

Comment: Eskir: The bigger picture is that this is a status update thing so the program needs to echo each individual file without messing about with any of the other status updates. If what you just explained right there will do that I can try it out

Comment: Oh, that's easy. You can do that with what I said to do. The time thing suggested below can do that too, but you still need to parse the date every time so not sure what you'd rather do (having a timestamp can be quite useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make each time a new file you could use time():

```
// change this line of code
$fOp = fopen("updates.txt","c+");
```

to:

```
$file_name = "updates_".time().".txt";
$fOp = fopen($file_name,"c+");
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped :) I also figured out how to echo this, but the issue now is that it disappears once you leave the page and come back. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Do you need to load last file, or all files? And you could use database for saving this (and loading back), this isn't the best method...

Comment: All files in specific "div"s. Still figuring out how to save the JS Elements for that as well.  It basically works like this: The user inputs their status update in a form, the user proceeds to click a button that creates a new JS Element with the status update in it. I use php to transfer and store the status, but I need to find out how to keep them there. Hope that explains it. :)

Comment: You need some counter for elements, like element1, element2, element3.. And when you do saving to file, you could use the same name to save to file, like updates_element1, updates_element2 and so on, and later on you could load your file by elements..